# How to set up index file for exposing Typescript library through NPM

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a TypeScript networking library that I've been working on and I want to include it in projects via npm and git (i.e. `npm install <my repo url>`).

I've created an index file at the root of the library project with the following:

```
import {GlueError as er} from './src/glue_error'
import {LogLevel as ll} from './src/log_level'
import {WSRouter as ro} from './src/node/ws_router'
import {WSClient as cl} from './src/node/ws_client'

export const Router = ro;
export const Client = cl;
export const LogLevel = ll;
export const Error = er;
```

When I `npm install` the library into my project though `tsc` can't seem to find the file. For example if I have a source file with the following:

```
import * as glue from "glue";

export class Admin {
    private _connection:glue.Client;
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error:(5, 30) TS2694:Namespace '"/Users/mattia/Repositories/drone_server/node_modules/glue/index"'has no exported member 'Client'.

Is there something I have to do besides `export`ing the `Client` to make this work? Is there some other approach that I should use to distribute a Typescript library?

P.S. - Here's the tsconfig.json I'm using for the project (not the library):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [ "./node_modules" ]
}
```

P.P.S. - I've tried not excluding node_modules, but no dice.